# LibGDX project doesn't run on my android device

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, libgdx

So i just created a libGDX project,imported it in intellij and wanted to run it on my android device then i encountered this error :

> Cause: class
>   "org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.IDEA$Mappings"'s signer
>   information does not match signer information of other classes in the
>   same package

Please can anybody tell me how to fix this?Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well i found how to solve it...It was the keystore that wasn't good, and it looks like the keystore was not creating when i was running my application .I tried to create one with the key tool but failed because it told me the key was tempered. **THE FIX WAS TO CREATE A APPLICATION IN ANDROID STUDIO AND RUN IT ON MY PHONE THEN THE KEYSTORE WOULD BE CREATED AND MY APPS WILL WORK AFTER...**

Comment: Thanks for the head ups!

Comment: Thank you so much! You ended a week of pain for me!

Answer (score 10):

@Gagiu Filip.

Instead of it, just run the following line in the terminal.

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

It will create a debug.keystore))

Comment: I had the exact same error in Android Studio 3.6.1 and LibGDX 1.9.10 and this solved my problem.

Comment: This worked for me, but i had to make sure i created the key in my ".android" folder.

Comment: Adding to what @WindupBeanie said, this is the .android folder in the user directory (C:\Users\<user>\.android)

Comment: I tried running the command but getting error        keytool : The term 'keytool' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify 
that the path is correct and try again.  I downloaded android studio today which is latest version and libgdx is also latest. I dont have any experience with android just using it for libgdx

Comment: Running this command solved the problem for me as well. Thank you! Note that you may need to adjust the file path ("~/.android/debug.keystore") depending on your OS and username.